# Can't parse a table child with xpath

Tags: python, lxml

I'm parsing a site with some messy html, they're 130 subsites and the only one that fails is the last one. The part in which fails is the bolded one. I get an empty list when I should be getting 3(parent and 2 childs). All sites have the same structure so I don't have a clue how to solve this.

```
from lxml.html import parse
# get a list of the urls of the foods to parse
main_site = "http://www.whfoods.com/foodstoc.php"
doc = parse(main_site).getroot()
doc.make_links_absolute()
sites = doc.xpath('/html/body//div[@class="full3col"]/ul/li/a/@href')

for site in sites:
   doc = parse(site).getroot()
   **table = doc.xpath("descendant::table[1]")[0]**
   #food info list
   table.xpath("//tr/td/table/tr/td/b/text()")
   # food nutrients list
   table.xpath("//tr/td/table[1]/tr/td/text()")
```

This is an html excerpt of the site that fails( [click here](http://www.whfoods.com/genpage.php?tname=foodspice&dbid=97) if you want to see it complete):

```
<html>
    <head>
    <body>
        <div id=mainpage">
            <div id="subcontent">
                 (40+ <p> tags with things inside)
                 <p>
                     <table>
                         <tbody>
                             <tr>
                                 <td>
                                     <table>
                                         <tbody>
                                             <tr>
                                                 <td>
                                                     <b>Food's name<br>other things</b>
                                                 </td>
                                             </tr>
                                             <tr>
                                             Heads of the table(not needed)
                                             </tr>
                                             <tr>
                                                 <td>nutrient name</td>
                                                 <td>dv</td>
                                                 <td>density</td>
                                                 <td>rating</td>
                                             </tr>
                                         </tbody>
                                     </table>
                                     <table> Not needed
                                     ...
                            All  remaining closing tags
```

Comment: Did you check for namespace declaration?

Comment: @Alejandro: Sorry, I don't know what you mean.

Comment: This is *not* an XPath question. An XPath expression can only be applied on a well-formed XML document (or in the worst case fragment). The linked to text is n't well-formed XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to validator.w3.org when pointed at `http://www.whfoods.com/genpage.php?tname=foodspice&dbid=97`:

```
Line 253, column 147: non SGML character number 150

  …ed mushrooms by Liquid Chromatography  Mass Spectroscopy. The 230th ACS Natio…
```

The problem character is between "Chromatography" and "Mass". The page is declared to be encoded in ISO-8859-1, but as often happens in that case, it is lying:

```
>>> import unicodedata as ucd
>>> ucd.name(chr(150).decode('cp1252'))
'EN DASH'
```

Perhaps lxml is being picky about this also (Firefox doesn't care).